# How to you create a table of counts between two columns without having to list every column name? (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, this is the part of my data set I'm interested in:

| EventID | Action | Actor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EventID1 | ActionB | ActorX |
| EventID2 | ActionB | ActorZ |
| EventID1 | ActionA | ActorY |
| EventID2 | ActionC | ActorZ |
| EventID3 | ActionA | ActorX |
| EventID3 | ActionB | ActorZ |
| EventID2 | ActionB | ActorZ |
| EventID2 | ActionA | ActorY |

I Want:

|  | ActorX | ActorY | ActorZ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ActionA | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| ActionB | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| ActionC | 0 | 0 | 1 |

The problem is I have LOTS of actors and actions--so I need a way of doing this without listing each one.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

You create this as *pairs* within a row, rather than as a matrix:

```
select t1.action, t1.actor, t2.actor, count(*)
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.action = t2.action
group by t1.action, t1.actor, t2.actor;
```

Pivoting the data into a matrix is best handled at the application layer.  You can construct dynamic SQL to do this as well.  Or you could construct a JSON data structure to contain the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Prepared statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html).

1. Set `@sql` & `@sql2` variable as `NULL`; in case the variable being used before, we're resetting it to `NULL`.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SET @sql2 = NULL;
```

2. Set `@sql` variable with list of actor adding `SUM()` as method of counting and `CASE` expression to match the actor value:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT(' SUM(CASE WHEN Actor = "', Actor,'" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ',Actor))
  INTO @sql
  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT Actor FROM mytable ORDER BY Actor) AS b;
```

At this point, when you run `SELECT @sql;`, you'll get this result:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Actor = "ActorX" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ActorX, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Actor = "ActorY" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ActorY, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Actor = "ActorZ" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ActorZ
```

3. Set `@sql2` variable with the final query combination of `SELECT ... FROM table` with the dynamically generated column that was set in `@sql` variable.

```
SET @sql2=CONCAT('SELECT Action,',@sql,' FROM mytable GROUP BY Action ORDER BY Action');
```

At this point, when you run `SELECT @sql2;`, you'll get this result:

```
SELECT Action, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Actor = "ActorX" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ActorX, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Actor = "ActorY" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ActorY, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Actor = "ActorZ" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ActorZ 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY Action 
ORDER BY Action
```

4. Prepare, execute then deallocate the statement with the following command;

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql2;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2b54cdd8363e99e226c322395cd7b589)